# How to reduce network speed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am writing a networking app, In there I just want to control the speed of the network (Increase and Decrease). Are there any solutions to achieve this?

Comment: Please eleborate on what you mean with "speed". Bandwidth? Throughput? Latency?

Comment: I means speed of Network

Comment: What is for you speed of Network

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for testing purposes and you're on a mac you can use the `Network Link Conditioner` tool from the Additional Tools for Xcode. https://developer.apple.com/download/all/